# Is the Time Complexity of assigning n values to an array of size n O(n)?

Tags: c, indexing, hash, time-complexity

I am trying Index mapping in Hashing to search an element in an array. A linear search would take O(n) to search an element in an array of size n. In hashing what we're doing is basically reducing the time complexity to O(1) by creating a 2d matrix of zeros (say hash[1000][2]) and reassigning hash[a[i]][0] to 1 if a[i] is positive and hash[-a[i]][1] if a[i] is negative. Here a[i] is the array from which we are supposed to search an element.

```
    for(i=0 ;i<n    ;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>=0)
            has[a[i]][0]=1;
        else
            has[-a[i]][1]=1;
    }
```

How much time does the above code take to execute?
Even by hashing, aren't we having a time complexity of O(n) just like linear search? Isn't what has consumed to assign n 1's in a 2d array of zeros equal to the time taken to search an element in a linear fashion?

Comment: Yes.  But that time is used only once, not every time you're searching.

Comment: Yes, creating the hash array takes O(n), but then each query takes O(1) time. So if there are O(n) queries, the time complexity using the hash array is O(n). But performing a linear search for O(n) queries would take O(n^2) time. In other words, it makes no sense to build the hash array to satisfy one query. But it does make sense if the time saved by the queries makes up for the time used to build the table.

Comment: In theory yes, your complexity will be O(n) + O(1) which is O(n) but in practice it will outperform your linear search (Assuming the way you're hashing doesn't cause too many collisions).

Comment: Yes! Makes complete sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Creating a hash array takes O(n) but creating a linear search array takes O(n) too.

Comment: Interesting and somewhat related, about the performance impact of preparing (sorting) an array and later using it, compared to linear search: http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/02/quicksort-binary-search-and-linear.html

Answer (score 0):

A typical thing to do here would be to maintain an array sorted by hash key, and then use a binary search to locate elements, giving worst-case time complexity of O(log n).

You can maintain the sort order by using the same binary search for inserting new elements as you use for finding existing elements.

That last point is important: as noted in comments, sorting before each search degrades search time to the point where brute-force linear search is faster for small datasets. But that overhead can be eliminated; the array *never needs to be sorted* if you maintain sort order when inserting new elements.

Comment: *"maintain an array sorted by hash key, and then use a binary search"* - the point of hashing is usually to enable use of a hash table, and when you're using that you can index directly without a binary search.  And your talk of maintaining sort order during insertion is misleading: if you have a sorted array you can binary-search to work out where to insert new elements, but then have to do an O(n) move operation on all existing elements after the insertion point to make space for the new element.  Binary search trees and hash tables allow relatively efficient insert and erase; not so arrays.

Comment: Sure, it wasn't meant to be misleading though, it's a tradeoff like anything else. The advantages are 1) you don't start with a bunch of empty space with nothing in it; everything is condensed, and as it grows you 2) don't end up with a bunch of things in buckets requiring O(n) time on the bucket once you find it, or 3) need to resize the entire hash table to allow for more buckets with less things in each bucket. I find it works well for situations where stored values change often, but keys aren't created/removed often, esp. when you occasionally need to iterate over all stored values.